# What good technology podcasts are out there?

Tags: podcast

Yes, Podcasts, those nice little Audiobooks I can listen to on the way to work. With the current amount of Podcasts, it's like searching a needle in a haystack, except that the haystack happens to be the Internet and is filled with too many of these "Hot new Gadgets" stuff :(

Now, even though **I** am mainly a .NET developer nowadays, maybe anyone knows some good Podcasts from people regarding the whole software lifecycle? Unit Testing, Continous Integration, Documentation, Deployment...

So - what are you guys and gals listening to?

---

Please note that the categorizations are somewhat subjective and may not be 100% accurate as many podcasts cover several areas. Categorization is made against what is considered the "main" area.

## General Software Engineering / Productivity

- [Stack Overflow ] [1](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/)(inactive, but still a good listen)
- [TekPub (Requires Paid Subscription)](http://tekpub.com)
- [Software Engineering Radio](http://www.se-radio.net/)
- [43 Folders](http://www.43folders.com/podcast)
- [Perspectives](http://perspectives.on10.net/)
- [Dr. Dobb's](http://www.drdobbs.com/tv/) (now a video feed)
- [The Pragmatic Podcast](http://www.pragprog.com/podcasts) (Inactive)
- [IT Matters](http://www.thoughtworks.com/what-we-say/podcasts.html)
- [Agile Toolkit Podcast](http://agiletoolkit.libsyn.com/)
- [The Stack Trace](http://thestacktrace.libsyn.com/) (Inactive)
- [Parleys](http://www.parleys.com/display/PARLEYS/Home#page=Home)
- [Techzing](http://techzinglive.com/)
- [The Startup Success Podcast](http://startuppodcast.wordpress.com/)
- [Berkeley CS class lectures](http://webcast.berkeley.edu/course_feeds.php)
- [FLOSS Weekly](http://twit.tv/FLOSS)
- [This Developer's Life](http://www.thisdeveloperslife.com/)

## .NET / Visual Studio / Microsoft

- [Herding Code](http://herdingcode.com/)
- [Hanselminutes](http://www.hanselminutes.com/)
- [.NET Rocks!](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/)
- [Deep Fried Bytes](http://deepfriedbytes.com/)
- [Alt.Net Podcast](http://altnetpodcast.com/) (inactive)
- [Polymorphic Podcast](http://www.polymorphicpodcast.com/) (inconsistent)
- [Sparkling Client (The Silverlight Podcast)](http://www.sparklingclient.com/)
- [dnrTV!](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx)
- [Spaghetti Code](http://feeds.feedburner.com/SpaghettiCodePodcasts)
- [ASP.NET Podcast](http://aspnetpodcast.com/CS11/Default.aspx)
- [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Media/Podcasts/)
- [Radio TFS](http://www.radiotfs.com/)
- [PowerScripting Podcast](http://feeds.feedburner.com/powerscripting)
- [The Thirsty Developer](http://thirstydeveloper.com/)
- [Elegant Code](http://elegantcode.com/elegantcode-cast/) (inactive)
- [ConnectedShow](http://www.connectedshow.com/)
- [Crafty Coders](http://craftycoders.com/?tag=/podcast)
- [Coding QA](http://codingqa.com)

## jQuery

- [yayQuery](http://yayquery.com/)
- [The official jQuery podcast](http://blog.jquery.com/2009/11/13/announcing-the-official-jquery-podcast/)

## Java / Groovy

- [The Java Posse](http://javaposse.com/)
- [Grails Podcast](http://www.grailspodcast.com/blog/list)
- [Java Technology Insider](http://www.javaworld.com/podcasts/jtech/)
- [Basement Coders](http://basementcoders.com/)

## Ruby / Rails

- [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/)
- [Rails Envy](http://railsenvy.com/podcast)
- [The Ruby on Rails Podcast](http://podcast.rubyonrails.org/)
- [Rubiverse](http://rubiverse.com/)
- [Ruby5](http://ruby5.envylabs.com/)

## Web Design / JavaScript / Ajax

- [WebDevRadio](http://webdevradio.com/)
- [Boagworld](http://boagworld.com/)
- [The Rissington podcast](http://therissingtonpodcast.co.uk/)
- [Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/by/category/podcasts)
- [YUI Theater](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/)

## Unix / Linux / Mac / iPhone

- [Mac Developer Network](http://www.mac-developer-network.com/)
- [Hacker Public Radio](http://www.hackerpublicradio.org/)
- [Linux Outlaws](http://www.linuxoutlaws.com/)
- [Mac OS Ken](http://macosken.com/)
- [LugRadio Linux radio show](http://lugradio.org/) (Inactive)
- [The Linux Action Show!](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?cat=4)
- [Linux Kernel Mailing List (LKML) Summary Podcast](http://www.kernelpodcast.org/)
- [Stanford's iPhone programming class](http://itunes.stanford.edu/)
- [Advanced iPhone Development Course - Madison Area Technical College](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/06/03/advanced-iphone-development-course-now-itunes-u)
- [WWDC 2010 Session Videos (requires Apple Developer registration)](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/)

## System Administration, Security or Infrastructure

- [RunAs Radio](http://feeds.feedburner.com/RunasRadio)
- [Security Now!](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm)
- [Crypto-Gram Security Podcast](http://crypto-gram.libsyn.com/)
- [Hak5](http://www.hak5.org/)
- [VMWare VMTN](http://blogs.vmware.com/vmtn/podcasts/index.html)
- [Windows Weekly](http://twit.tv/ww)
- [PaulDotCom Security](http://pauldotcom.com/)
- [The Register - Semi-Coherent Computing](http://www.theregister.co.uk/hardware/semi_coherent/podcast.rss)
- [FeatherCast](http://feathercast.org/)

## General Tech / Business

- [Tekzilla](http://revision3.com/tekzilla/)
- [This Week in Tech](http://twit.tv/twit)
- [The Guardian Tech Weekly](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/series/techweekly)
- [PCMag Radio Podcast](http://www.pcmag.com/category2/0,2806,2007098,00.asp) (Inactive)
- [Entrepreneurship Corner](http://ecorner.stanford.edu/)
- [Manager Tools](http://www.manager-tools.com/)

## Other / Misc. / Podcast Networks

- [IT Conversations](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/)
- [Retrobits Podcast](http://retrobits.libsyn.org/)
- [No Agenda Netcast](http://cagematch.dvorak.org/index.php/board,45.0.html)
- [Cranky Geeks](http://www.crankygeeks.com/)
- [The Command Line](http://thecommandline.net/)
- [Freelance Radio](http://www.freelanceswitch.com/podcasts/)
- [IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/podcast/)
- [The Register - Open Season](http://www.theregister.co.uk/software/open_season/podcast.rss)
- [Drunk and Retired](http://www.drunkandretired.com/thepodcast/)
- [Technometria](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/technometria.html)
- [Sod This](http://www.sodthis.com/podcast/)
- [Radio4Nerds](http://www.radio4nerds.com/)
- [Hacker Medley](http://hackermedley.org)

Comment: I suggest that everybody writes exactly one podcast per answer (post several answers if needed), such that the voting tells how the other people think about this one podcast. And how about a one sentence description?

Comment: @Michael, could you please consolidate all the podcasts you got in to this question for easy access

Comment: just up voted you to put you on 100 yay

Comment: Surly there is a way to organise this question a bit better. it impossible to make sense or find stuff.. there are tons of duplicate answers.

Comment: Yeah this is so much better! I think its time to close http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423/best-net-podcasts/985126#985126

Comment: Has SO been reduced to building collections of links? This looks my univeristy webpage in 1993. And like my 1993 webpage, it's out of date the moment it's written.

Comment: Except unlike a web site this is a wiki - you can fix changed links, remove dead site,s and vote up/down new and old entries.
It's more like the music charts!

Comment: Wow, thanks for consolidating all of these here.  I never knew there were so many different programming podcasts!

Comment: @skaffman why you hating on ppl providing links to well known points of information on the web? The simple fact that it is posted on SO makes the link more valuable and helps other programmers to learn about it.

Comment: @Martin Except that 1. People aren't going to browse 4 pages of results and to vote 2. Especially now that the results are consolidated in the question 3. This question doesn't get as much traction today as when it was created (so votes don't reflect anything).

Comment: While I appreciate this podcast list, I think skaffman makes a valid point.  Such lists may be more appropriate on a site such as Delicious whose purpose is to collect links.  Even Wikipedia may be more appropriate since each page does not have a list of answers.  As Pascal points out, answer votes don't matter much as the list changes or becomes out of date.

Answer (score 91):

I like

**General Software**

- [Stackoverflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/) (perhaps too obvious)
- [Deep Fried Bytes](http://deepfriedbytes.com/)
- [Hanselminutes](http://www.hanselminutes.com/)
- [Software Engineering Radio](http://www.se-radio.net/) (via Brenden)
- [Herding Code](http://herdingcode.com/)

**Dot Net**

- [Alt.NET Podcast](http://altnetpodcast.com/)
- [Polymorphic Podcast](http://www.polymorphicpodcast.com/)

**Productivity**

- [43 Folders](http://www.43folders.com/podcast)

Comment: What's the url to 43 folders feed? His site sucks a lot or it's me, but I can't find it.

Comment: What happened to the Alt.NET Podcast? I haven't seen a new show in a couple of months. Is it 'over'?

Comment: All from General Software are great! And I can see, that 43 Folders are broadcastin again!

Answer (score 63):

My list:

[Hanselminutes](http://www.hanselminutes.com/)

[.NET Rocks!](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/)

[Herding Code](http://herdingcode.com/)

[Deep Fried Bytes](http://deepfriedbytes.com/)

[Spaghetti Code](http://feeds.feedburner.com/SpaghettiCodePodcasts)

[The Sparkling Client](http://www.sparklingclient.com/)

[Plumbers @ Work](http://plumbersatwork.com/)

[Polymorphic Podcast](http://www.polymorphicpodcast.com/)

[ALT.NET Podcast](http://altnetpodcast.com/)

[ASP.NET Podcast](http://aspnetpodcast.com/CS11/Default.aspx)

[Radio TFS](http://www.radiotfs.com/)

[PowerScripting Podcast](http://feeds.feedburner.com/powerscripting)

[Software Engineering Radio](http://www.se-radio.net/)

[stackoverflow Podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/)

[The Thirsty Developer](http://thirstydeveloper.com/)

[ThoughtWorks - IT Matters Podcast](http://www.thoughtworks.com/what-we-say/podcasts.html)

[Agile Toolkit Podcast](http://agiletoolkit.libsyn.com/)

[Ajaxian Podcast](http://ajaxian.com/by/category/podcasts)

[Pragmatic Podcasts](http://pragprog.com/podcasts)

[Channel 9 Audio Feed](http://tinyurl.com/25l95t)

**EDIT: Missed one:**
[Elegant Code Cast](http://elegantcode.com/cast/)

Comment: I think Plumbers @ Work is gone. Cute picture on the site, though! :)

Answer (score 62):

This one's not specifically about development, but [Security Now](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm) from Steve Gibson and Leo Laporte is an excellent discussion of security issues.  I think it's a must-listen for just about any computer user who's concerned about security, and especially for web developers who are responsible both for the security of their site and at least partially responsible for their users' security.

Comment: Yeah, it's great. And the best episode was the one about PDP-8 (Episode 177) http://snipurl.com/sn177

Comment: +1 for Mr. Gibson. It's great that the podcast is so regular, too.

Comment: @RCIX My comment is from Mar 13 '09, the Vitamin D podcast was aired 13 Aug 2009 so at that time PDP-8 was the best show ever.
I agree that Vitamin D is also great, it seems "out of theme" episodes are the best!

Comment: The Portable Dog Killer episode was great (and hysterical) as well: http://www.twit.tv/sn248.

Answer (score 48):

I **love** [FLOSS Weekly](http://twit.tv/FLOSS). Another Twit Podcast where Leo and Randal Schwartz interview open source geeks. My favorite was their interview with Dan Ingalls (Smalltalk/Squeak fame). I also enjoyed their interview of Richard Hipp (SQLite).

Comment: And more recently Linus Torvalds.

Comment: Yeah I caught that. God, he came across as an arrogant prig.

Comment: Randal and Leo hyped him up before and after though calling him a "god" (I think that was the word) and what not.

Comment: Yeah they did. He's smart.. and had good timing.. But god.. nahhh. But I just listened to their interview with Kent Beck. That was great!

Comment: I think the show has taken a bit of a hit since Leo stopped hosting it. Nothing against Randal Schwartz (he is doing a great job), but a really tech-heavy show like this one seems to need a less-techy host to ask the guest(s) the basic, obvious questions that are sometimes overlooked.

Answer (score 35):

Am I going to be downmodded for suggesting that the Stack Overflow podcast is hilariously bad as a podcast?  Anywho, you can find it, and a number of not-bad podcasts at
[itconversations.com](http://itconversations.com).

As this question asked for a "good" rather than "exhaustive" list, then this is obviously just my opinion.  My opinion bounces between .NET and Java and just geek.  And obvious omissions would reflect my opinion on "good". (Ahem, DNR.)

The rest of these are easily found by doing a podcast search in iTunes, or just googling (I'll do some repeating here to condense the list):

- [Buzz Out Loud](http://bol.cnet.com) (General Consumer Tech, Daily)
- This Week in Tech (aka TWiT.  Weekly Consumer Tech.)
- The Java Posse (Weekly.)
- Google Developer Podcast (which went long fallow, but seems to be coming
  back, possible renamed as the Google Code Review. Schedule uncertain, technologies vary.)
- [Hanselminutes](http://hanselminutes.com) (Usually, but not always, .NET-related)
- MacBreak Weekly (The Mac version of TWiT)
- Polymorphic Podcast (All .NET, usually ASP.NET)
- Pixel8ed (All .NET, focused on UI.  Same guy who does Polymorphic Podcast)
- tech5 (Consumer Tech.  Mostly a fun waste of 5 minutes because Dvorak is so... Spolsky.)

Comment: Apparently you haven't been downmodded ;)

Comment: I second This Week in Tech. Leo Laporte (sp?) is an excellent host and some of the guests are top notch.

Comment: Upvote, Buzz Army/Brigade/Militia/WTF? :) Seriously, BOL is great.

Comment: I also applaud Scott Hanselman for completely mocking his name. (Not in the software development sense of the word "mocking"). It's also great - especially the fact that he doesn't just cover MS stuff - they had a Mono guy from Novell on a couple of shows ago.

Answer (score 29):

In the Stack Overflow podcast [SE-radio](http://www.se-radio.net/) was mentioned. It's pretty in depth.

Also if you are an aspiring JavaScript developer, the Douglas Crockford "The JavaScript Programming Language" and "Advanced JavaScript" talks on [YUI Developer Theatre](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/) are excellent. There are a few other gems on the podcast too.

Answer (score 26):

I listen to the [javaposse](http://javaposse.com) regularly, they cover mostly Java, but not solely.

Answer (score 24):

- **JavaPosse** If you want to hear all that you (n)ever wanted to know about closures (7/2010 - This is actually a good podcast, but now it's all you (n)ever wanted to know about apple & android)
- **.NET Rocks** For when you want to hear the billionth interview about databinding controls in the trenches during the transition from VB6 to VB.NET
- **Stack Overflow** You really do want to hear a guy who doesn't know C debate a guy who pretends to have invented it, or something, or maybe just listen for spoilers to wallee
- **Security Now!** You want to listen to someone who thinks he's the most ingenious security architect in the world, because he writes EVERYTHING IN ASSEMBLER (no, I'm not kidding), while overlooking the obvious solutions to problems that have existed for years.  Please don't listen to this thinking it's good
- **Yahoo! Dev Network** - I haven't seen a lot of good stuff here, but Crockford's talks on advanced JavaScript are wonderful

Comment: -1: I doubt that anyone on this thread knows as much about low-level protocols as Steve Gibson of Security Now! While he has his idiosyncrasies, he recognizes other experts in different security areas. If you listen to his podcasts and don't learn anything valuable, you're not really listening.

Comment: @TrueWill - Did you catch the one where he overengineered a solution to the "duplicate order" problem and then spent weeks figuring out that the main problem was that people double-click buttons (and his initial solution didn't help)?  Then acted like both solutions were something he invented (not even close)?  Maybe that was just a particularly bad episode, but it didn't leave me impressed.

Comment: Yeah, my only objection to Steve Gibson is that he doesn't seem to be very "plugged in" to the mainstream developer/security research community, so when he arrives at some concept or solution on his own (because he *is* a sharp guy), he sort of naturally assumes that he came up with something revolutionary.

I also think he could cut the "security news" segment of the show way back. Seriously, not every single tiny security patch to Firefox (for example) is "news".

Answer (score 20):

**Suggestion:**  If you post each of your recommended podcasts as a *separate* answer then people can vote for your "answer".

BTW, Joel discussed this on the Stack Overflow Podcast (can't find the reference in the transcript Wiki) and suggested something like:
- Post your suggested "favorite" (tech podcast, in this case) as a question:   "Do you like < > podcast and tag it with "technology podcast".

The beauty of this is that we get a simple poll. Yes, it would be nice to actually *have* a poll but that's not yet a Stack Overflow feature.

Answer (score 19):

The [Google Developer Podcast](http://google-code-updates.blogspot.com/2007/05/introducing-google-developer-podcast.html) is good.

Answer (score 15):

Brad's list is pretty good. I also listen to:

- [Sparkling Client](http://www.sparklingclient.com/) (Silverlight specific)
- Jon Udell's [Perspectives](http://perspectives.on10.net/) series
- [Herding Code](http://herdingcode.com) (shameless plug for a podcast I put on
  with Kevin Dente, Scott "lazycoder" Koon, and K. Scott
  Allen. We recently [interviewed Jeff Atwood about 
  Stack Overflow](http://herdingcode.com/?p=36), discussing both how the site is 
  designed and the technology behind it.

Answer (score 15):

The way I understand the question, you are asking for developer centric podcast. My personal number one is *[Late Night Cocoa](http://www.mac-developer-network.com/category/shows/podcasts/lnc/)* from the ***[Mac Developer Network](http://mac-developer-network.com/)*** followed by *[Mac Developer Roundtable](http://www.mac-developer-network.com/category/shows/podcasts/mdr/)*. Although I agree that every developer should probably listen to Steve Gibson's *[Security Now!](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm)* (with Leo Laporte's ***[TWiT network](http://thisweekintech.com/)***).

For general tech stuff, check out other TWiT podcasts: *[This week in Tech](http://thisweekintech.com/twit)*, *[MacBreak Weekly](http://thisweekintech.com/mbw)*, *[MacBreack Tech](http://macbreaktech.com/)* (with ***[PixelCorps](http://www.pixelcorps.tv/)***), *[Windows Weekly](http://thisweekintech.com/ww)* and *[FLOSS Weekly](http://thisweekintech.com/FLOSS)*

On a side note: relevant to some developers who think about becoming a Micro-ISV in the Apple Universe: *[MacSB - Mac Software Business](http://mac-developer-network.com/podcasts/macsb/index.html)*

Comment: Great recommendations. You should have posted them as individual answers and I would have voted up each one.

Answer (score 14):

I found this on a similar discussion, I think it was at Reddit:
[UC Berkeley Webcast](http://webcast.berkeley.edu/course_feeds.php)
I found it most useful, since it podcasts entire classes from Berkley courses such as Operating Systems and System Programming, The Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs, Data Structures and Programming Methodology, among others.

Comment: http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs162/fa08/ here is the courses actual site, lots of good information

Answer (score 12):

Almost all of my favorite podcasts have already been mentioned but not the No 1. Do yourself a favor and listen to the best podcast ever, [Linux radio show - LugRadio](http://lugradio.org).

Answer (score 10):

If you are into web design and website creation then I recommend [Boagworld](http://boagworld.com/) and also [The Rissington podcast](http://therissingtonpodcast.co.uk/) even if you are not.

Answer (score 9):

Also make sure you don't miss the [dnrTV webcast show](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx) that Carl Franklin (the man behind .NET rocks) publishes. Even if it's a not a podcast and requires a more attention while watching it it's really informative and if you're into .NET and Microsoft related techniques you'll learn a lot.

Answer (score 9):

I can second Jon Galloway's mention of [Herding Code](http://herdingcode.com), and since I have absolutely nothing to do with the podcast, with nothing to gain, my opinion may be more valuable than his :-).

There are only a few there as it's relatively new, but they are jam packed with good stuff that is very relevant to today's programming paradigms and strategies.

I also love the smooth format they've got going since 4 guys all giving input on a topic can make for a very jerky conversation with all (most?) of them dialed in, but whether it's the post editing or just a good format, either way it comes across as a very comfortable listening experience to the end user. Keep it up guys!

Hope that helps,
Rob G

Answer (score 8):

It does not seem like this one was mentioned yet.

http://thecommandline.net/ --
 "Exploring the rough edges where technology, society and public policy meet."

He does a weekly News show and a weekly topics show.

From the website,
**Endorsement**:
"Thoughtful, informative, and deep, a real plunge into the geeky end of the news-pool. There's great analysis and rumination, as well as detailed explanations of important security issues with common OSes and so on." -- Cory Doctorow

Answer (score 8):

Besides Stack Overflow of course, here are mine.

- Many have already mentioned [Hanselminutes](http://www.hanselminutes.com/hanselminutes_mp3Direct.xml).
- Some have already mentioned [.NET Rocks!](http://feeds.feedburner.com/netRocksFullMp3Downloads)
- Not quite as many have mentioned [RunAs Radio](http://feeds.feedburner.com/RunasRadio).

I can't believe the size of some of these lists. With podcasts, I like to keep the list short and the quality high. As such, I tend to skip the aggregates like ITConversations et. al.

Comment: I'm a former IT person who recently transitioned to development.  I LOVE RunAs Radio.  Richard Campbell is one of those guys that gives me hope that I can bridge the gap between the two disciplines.  It lets me keep my hands in IT and applies a lot of IT knowledge with a developer bent.

Answer (score 8):

Not hardcore technology but I really enjoy [Drunk and Retired](http://www.drunkandretired.com/podcast/).  It's like you're talking to your programmer buddy mixed in with life stuff.

Comment: That's actually a pretty cool Podcast. I like those "chaotic" ad-hoc ones.

Answer (score 7):

Extending on what [Mike Powell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205/mike-powell) has to say, I am actually a big fan of almost all of the podcasts at http://www.twit.tv.  Most of the content is watered down a bit, but some of the speakers are top notch thinkers - especially on "This Week in Tech", the flagship program.

Oh - and Car Talk on NPR but those guys hardly EVER get into the SDLC!

Answer (score 7):

- [FLOSS Weekly](http://twit.tv/FLOSS)

  - [Pragmatic Podcasts](http://www.pragprog.com/podcasts)
  - [Rails Envy](http://railsenvy.com/podcast)
  - [Webdev Radio](http://webdevradio.com/)

Answer (score 7):

If you started out on an 8 bit machine, don't forget your roots:
[The Retrobits Podcast](http://retrobits.libsyn.org/)

Answer (score 7):

A good weekly update to the Ruby on Rails world: [Rails Envy](http://www.railsenvy.com/).

The [thestacktrace](http://thestacktrace.libsyn.com/) is good general programming podcast, which covers every thing from git to [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language)).

Comment: I love that podcast! I ain't got no rspec, and I don't do ruby or rails but I love listening to Jason and Greggggg.

Answer (score 6):

If you're interested in Linux, [Linux Action Show](http://www.linuxactionshow.com/) is a wonderful podcast !

It's about Linux news, distributions and softwares releases and also Linux based hardware testing (like drobo, Amazon Kindle and so on).
It's very good quality and the hosts, Brian and Chris, sounds amazing.

It's my number one podcast !

Also, I've just discovered that IBM offers some [developer podcasts](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/podcast/) which seems very interesting, some are from Erich Gamma by the way. Of course, it's a little bit more Java and Eclipse oriented (It's IBM).

Comment: It's too bit the Linux Action Show has changed its format and added a lot of irrelevant other shows to their list.

Comment: Yes, I've preferred too the long form of the Linux Action Show podcast, but I understand their willing to go to a video format.

Answer (score 5):

http://herdingcode.com/

Answer (score 4):

Plus one for the following:

- [The Java Posse](http://www.javaposse.com)
- [Software Engineering Radio](http://www.se-radio.net)
- [The Grails Podcast](http://www.grails.org/Grails+Podcast)

Answer (score 4):

My favorite is [Manager Tools](http://www.manager-tools.com). Technically it is a business podcast, but very valuable for programmers or other individual contributors working in corporate environments. Been listening for 3 years, new to StackOverflow

-- Mike

Answer (score 4):

[Linux Outlaws](http://www.linuxoutlaws.com) are pretty good.  They discuss GNU/Linux distros, software and IT news.

Answer (score 3):

[Elegant Code Cast](http://elegantcode.com/elegantcode-cast/)

Answer (score 2):

I took all of the podcasts from the answers scoring 5 or better (and those in the original question) and added them to an aggregated page on Cullect.com:

http://www.cullect.com/StackOverflow-Recommended-Podcasts

It provides a handy way to get a glimpse of these podcasts as well as a way to preview them if you're in a hurry or don't want to wade through all of the duplicates in the answers. I'm currently set up as the only curator of the "cullection", but if someone else wants to help keep it adjusted as the answers change, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty much hooked to:

- The Java Posse
- Software Engineering Radio

Answer (score 2):

I'll add [Crypto-Gram Security Podcast](http://crypto-gram.libsyn.com/). Basically, Dan Henage reading [Bruce Schneier](http://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram.html) newsletter Crypto-Gram.

Most of the other podcasts I listen to have been mentioned (TwiT, Security Now!, Cranky Geeks).

my 2c

Answer (score 2):

[Technometria](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/technometria.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Cranky Geeks](http://www.crankygeeks.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my list:

- [The Java Posse](http://javaposse.com/) - a must for Java programmers
- [FLOSS Weekly](http://twit.tv/FLOSS) - On open source projects, usually very geekish, but Leo Laporte is very funny
- [Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) - I believe most of the readers know what I'm talking about...
- [Software Engineering Radio](http://www.se-radio.net/) - Very interesting interviews on various aspects
- [FeatherCast](http://feathercast.org/) - Seldom updated, interviews on Apache projects
- [Parleys.com](http://www.parleys.com/) - Lectures served as podcast, highly biased to the Spring project

Not strictly technical, but highly recommended

- [Entrepreneurial Thought Leaders](http://edcorner.stanford.edu/) - Lectures who built companies or other endeavours. Very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

[The MDN Show](http://itpc://feeds2.feedburner.com/TheMdnShow) for General Macintosh business topics.
[cocoaFusion](http://www.cocoafusion.net/) and [coreInt](http://coreint.org/) for in-depth Cocoa topics.

Answer (score 2):

I recently stumbled across a new podcast named [Hacker Medley](http://hackermedley.org/).  It's a short (~15 min) podcast with Nat Friedman and Alex Gravely.  I found the first 3 episodes quite entertaining!

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Overflow podcast is the reason I'm now here. Jeff, unfortunately, is a poor project manager in terms of managing expectations and setting timelines -- yet the beta has arrived, and it's pretty decent! The .NET world is alien to me, so I've enjoyed the Stack Overflow podcast.

This Week in Tech is another podcast I listen to regularly. Unfortunately, I feel that none of the panelists other than Leo Laporte does any homework prior to the show, so many of the opinions (especially John C. Dvorak's) are uninformed.

I recently started listening to IT Conversations podcasts, and I got enough good information that I donated. The selection is mixed, but I really like talks from various conferences that I was unable to attend.

Thanks to other people who responded with links to other podcasts I haven't heard of. I'm a newbie, so I can't bump up scores yet.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily something you can pop on your iPod and just chill to, but [Diggnation](http://diggnation.com) is a hillarious video podcast with Kevin Rose and Alex Albrecht.

They talk about "some of the top stories on the user-submitted news site digg.com". This doesn't really have much in the way of software development (though sometimes a story pops up with that), but is great for entertainment value.

Answer (score 1):

Not a technology podcast, but I really have to mention [FreelanceRadio](http://freelanceswitch.com/podcasts/). A really great and sometimes hilarious resource. I'm listening to them in the morning, on the way to work. And sometimes feel really stupid just giggling by myself :P

Answer (score 1):

I listen to The Guardian's [TechWeekly](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/series/techweekly), it's very informed for being done by journalists for a mainstream newspaper. Well produced and up to date. Has a focus on Britain and Europe.

Answer (score 1):

My list is pretty similar to the rest -
TWIT, MBW, .NET Rocks, Hanselminutes, Polymorphic Podcast and specifically for Mac developers the [Mac developer network](http://www.mac-developer-network.com/) has some a couple of good podcasts

Answer (score 1):

I do enjoy all the podcasts from the TWIT network, though FLOSS Weekly and Security Now are my favorite "techie" podcasts.
I actually have never heard the Stack Overflow podcast, but will definitely be giving it a try after seeing all the recommendations here.

Also, I believe that Alex Lindsay (of the Pixel Corps, and frequently on Macbreak Weekly on TWIT) will be starting a very technical podcast on Mac development. I'm looking forward to this, as I've been primary a Java programmer, and am interested in learning Xcode and Obj-C.

Answer (score 1):

My favourites are:

- Stack Overflow
- TWiT
- Security Now

I like listening to John C. Dvorak on TWiT, though I've never tried his other podcasts. He really knows his stuff and is frequently funny, but sometimes he's just an annoying old grump.

I used to listen to [PaulDotCom Security Weekly](http://pauldotcom.com/), but they talk an awful lot about penetration testing and not so much about other aspects of computer security.

Comment: what I always miss at these security podcasts are solutions. They simply find problems. That's easy. But they normally don't suggest fixes that are related to development and could matter to us.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow
This Week in Tech
Security Now

As I learn more about programming I'll add more to my list.
Adding 43 folders now.

Answer (score 1):

Top on my list are:

1. Software Engineering Radio
2. Java Posse
   Sometimes I also listen to:
   The ASP.NET podcast

I keep an eye on iTunes U as some courses have the perfect price (free) from top-notch Universities around the world. E.g. Computer Language Engineering from MIT.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth subscribing to the [Google Tech Talk YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/googletechtalks). It's a video podcast with a bunch of really interesting, wide-ranging talks given to Google but (usually) outside speakers.

Past presenters include Linus Torvals, Guido van Rossum, Merlin Mann and Larry Wall. The video is usually just the slides so (depending on the speaker) you might not need to watch.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Technology Insider](http://www.javaworld.com/podcasts/jtech/) is what I found when I went looking for a Java equivalent of .NET Rocks! The interviewer is an enthusiastic amateur, and the guests are usually good.

Answer (score 1):

I've just started listening to the irreverent [Sod This](http://www.sodthis.com) podcast series, hosted by Gary Short and Oliver Sturm of DevExpress. They are fairly entertaining and mildly educational with a guest slot, slightly sweary though.

Answer (score 1):

My favorites:

1. thirsty developer
2. pixel8d
3. stackoverflow
4. dotnetrocks
5. alt.net podcast
6. codecast
7. hanselminutes

cheers

Answer (score 1):

My top 3:

This Week in Tech (Leo Laporte, et. al)

Security Now (Leo Laporte + Steve Gibson)

Windows Weekly (Leo Laporte + Paul Thurrott)

Answer (score 1):

[The Connected Show](http://www.connectedshow.com) covers new Microsoft Technologies and other interesting topics for the developer community.

Answer (score 1):

[LKML Summary podcast](http://kernelpodcast.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I am the creator of Connected Show (http://www.ConnectedShow.com) and really want to thank this thread for posting us in the list. We are new and would love to get more listeners and more feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't seen the [Security Catalyst](http://www.securitycatalyst.com/) for security. I used to prefer this over the one leo laporte does when I acutally had time to listen to such things.

[Boagworld](http://boagworld.com/) was an ok one for basic web design/dev stuff.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

- [PHP Abstract](http://devzone.zend.com/podcasts/phpabstract)
- [ZendCon Sessions](http://devzone.zend.com/podcasts/zendconsessions)

Answer (score 1):

[Misfit Geek Podcast](http://misfitgeek.com/podcast/misfit-geek-podcast/) (formerly JoeOn.NET)

By Joe Stagner.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget [The Flex Show](http://www.theflexshow.com/blog/).

Answer (score 1):

I find the [PC Pro Podcast](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/podcast) a good weekly round up, which complements the monthly paper magazine in the UK, for PCs, Windows software and gadgets.

[This Week in Testing](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/this-week-in-testing/id348357035) can also be informative and fun, as a round up of blogs and opinions from the world of automated tests.

Some of the US based shows like the TWiT network are too advert heavy for my taste.

I also recently found the Ted Talks (in video, or audio only) on iTunes, quite a few of which are technical or speculative with a very high quality of speaker.

Edit: Added The Guardian's [Tech Weekly](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/series/techweekly)

Answer (score 1):

[37signals now has a podcast](http://37signals.com/podcast) with Jason Fried and [David Heinemeier Hansson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Heinemeier_Hansson) (creator of Ruby on Rails)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't found [Code cast](http://www.codemag.com/codecast) in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest someone with the reputation to do it revise this question to say, "What good technology podcasts are out there?"

I've got all kinds of audio fiction I could recommend, but then this question really runs off into the weeds.

Answer (score 0):

All of the tech podcasts I listen to have been mentioned, but as long as we're discussing video I'd like to mention [Hak.5](http://www.hak5.org/).  It is more focused on using existing programs rather than coding, but it has some good hardware segments, and it can often be an excellent source of inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I've been happy with [Stack Overflow](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html).

I listen to / watch a few others:

- [No Agenda](http://cagematch.dvorak.org/index.php/board,45.0.html)
- [This Week In Tech](http://twit.tv/twit)
- [Cranky Geeks](http://www.crankygeeks.com/)

But the constant MS/Google/Apple/Yahoo fluff of these is
getting really old.

I've listened to a couple [Hanselminutes](http://www.hanselminutes.com/) and might start
listening more regularly.

I'd like to find some that deal with actual software
engineering issues and not just "tech gossip".

Comment: Try Software Engineering Radio for actual issues, it's more heavyweight than those TWIT gossipy podcasts.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Brian Deacon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409/brian-deacon)** wrote:
>
> Dvorak is so... Spolsky.

I can't describe why, but I agree.

Answer (score 0):

My favorites are:

- Hanselminutes
- .NET Rocks
- StackOverflow
- SoftwareEngeneeringRadio

TWiT and CrankyGeeks I listen to if I want a laugh or get mad, they are horrible.

Answer (score 0):

It's not software, but I frequently watch the [Tekzilla](http://revision3.com/tekzilla/) podcasts. Love me some Veronica Belmont / Patrick Norton!

Also, all of the others already mentioned - Stack Overflow, TWiT, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Podcasts from [Dr.Dobbs Journal](http://www.ddj.com/mediaCenter/moreMediaCenter.jhtml?site_article_type=160901008&start=1)

   2. [ITConversations](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/)
   3. [SE-Radio](http://www.se-radio.net/)
   4. [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Media/Podcasts/)

Answer (score 0):

Something I didn't see mentioned is [PCMag Radio](http://www.pcmag.com/category2/0,2806,2007098,00.asp). That's a more consumer tech-oriented show, but they do geek out fairly often, and the chatter is always interesting.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to many of the other great ones listed, here are a couple of others for specific technologies that I regularly listen to:

- [This Week in Django](http://blog.michaeltrier.com/tags/twid)
- [VMware Communities Roundtable](http://blogs.vmware.com/vmtn/podcasts/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Over this summer I've enjoyed:

- StackOverflow
- SERadio - sometimes this feels too enterprise-y for me, but it's definitely the most technical, and the European (German?) hosts are a hoot.
- Hanselminutes and DNR - some aspects of these shows get annoying, but they frequently have interesting guests talking about interesting things, which is where the money is.

I echo the sentiment about the difference between tech gossip (TWiT, Diggnation, etc) and software development podcasts; while the former can sometimes be entertaining, I've found they tend towards the audio equivalent of Digg rather than Hacker News, programming.reddit, or, hopefully, StackOverflow.

I'll be checking out the other suggestions people gave.

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy both [Security Now](http://twit.tv/sn) and [Windows Weekly](http://twit.tv/ww), both a part of the [TWiT network](http://twit.tv/).  You may want to check out the TWiT network, since they have a variety of tech related podcasts.

Also, as seems common here, [Hanselminutes](http://hanselminutes.com/) is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

What a great bunch of answers - Now I've got a number of podcasts to add to my listening list!

My current list is StackOverflow, TWiT and Mac OS Ken.
I tried to get into SERadio a few months ago but couldn't really engage myself with the podcast - Great introductory material, but I felt a lot of the shows were a bit 'beginner-y'.

Answer (score 0):

There's tons of tech podcasts.


Some that I've subscribed to:

Daily shows

- [WebbAlert](https://miroguide.com/channels/3066)
- [Loaded](https://www.miroguide.com/channels/5651)

Non-Dailys

- [Cranky Geeks](https://www.miroguide.com/channels/1014)
- [DL.TV](https://www.miroguide.com/channels/1430)

And as you can see, I am using Miro to get them. (which is a nice X-platform vodcast catcher :-) )

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have subscribed to quite a few podcasts but the ones I try and listen to weekly are:

1. [Se-Radio](http://feeds.feedburner.com/se-radio)
2. [Hanselminutes](http://feeds.feedburner.com/HanselminutesCompleteMP3)
3. [.NET Rocks](http://feeds.feedburner.com/netRocksFullMp3Downloads)
4. [Polymorphic Podcast](http://polymorphicpodcast.com/podcast/feed/)
5. [RunAsRadio](http://feeds.feedburner.com/RunasRadio)

I have a 35 minute commute to work each morning (bus) and I like watching the [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Feeds/RSS/) feed on my zune.

Answer (score 0):

I listen to and watch:
* this week in tech
* Cranky Geeks
* Security Now
* This Week in Media
* Tech5

Answer (score 0):

My list includes:

```
  .NET Rocks!
  RunAs Radio
  TWiT
  Stack Overflow (but then again, we wouldn't be in Beta if we didn't)
  Channel 9
  Hanselminutes
```

Pretty much the same as everybody else.  Just goes to show you why podcasts are important to developing your art.

Answer (score 0):

My most regular listens are:

- Java Posse
- Software Engineering Radio
- Stack Overflow
- Agile Toolkit Podcast (intermittent)

Also, if you haven't heard the OOPSLA 2007 podcasts (keynote/main sessions recorded and podcasted) they're definitely worth a listen, although it's a fairly short run.

Answer (score 0):

Two others not mentioned yet are The Register's [Open Season](http://www.theregister.co.uk/software/open_season/podcast.rss) (about the Open Source industry) and [Semi Coherent Computing](http://www.theregister.co.uk/hardware/semi_coherent/podcast.rss) (which loosely is about enterprise hardware).

I'm not sure if Open Season has any more legs left in it though, since Ashley Vance (the apparent 'driver' of the podcast) has recently left El Reg for The New York Times.  That said, the past year's worth of episodes are great and include some notable guests.

Answer (score 0):

I am going out on a limb here to say that, don't get caught up in too many podcasts or blogs, but rather dive into technology/code and good tech books.

although +1 to;

- Thoughtworks - IT matters
- Software Engineering Radio
- Pragmatic podcasts
- Alt.Net podcasts
- Hanselminutes

and while not strictly technology

- Enterprise Thought Leaders from Stanford University, which often has speakers from fortune 500 and tech startups on how they made it.

Answer (score 0):

My list includes:
Herding Code, Deep Fried Bytes, Polymorohic Podcast, Pixel8, .Net Rocks, Hanselminutes, Powerscripting podcast.  Full list: http://rtipton.wordpress.com/podcasts/

Answer (score 0):

Many of the above, plus TED talks and Shareware Radio. Links here: http://successfulsoftware.net/category/podcasts/

Answer (score 0):

My favorite has been the Stack Overflow podcast just because it is reality based. ALT.NET has good content. Software Engineering Radio and Hanselminutes are informative. ThoughtWorks is marginal for me.

I'll try the others!

Answer (score 0):

I extract DNRTV's audio and listen to it as a podcast (or have it run as a video on my Archos media player and just listen to it).
I don't have time to watch it for an hour. Usually I can follow the discussion without watching the video.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the podcasts I listened to are already discussed above.

- .NET Rocks
- HanselMinutes
- RunAsRadio
- Mondays (for when you are bored with development stuffs)
- Herding Code
- Arcast (used to)
- AudibleAjax
- OpenWeb

There are some bits from OOPSLA that were interesting as well (not long running podcasts, but it's nice to hear).

Answer (score 0):

[Hacker Public Radio](http://www.hackerpublicradio.org/) is an excellent source of podcasts on a broad range of technical topics.

Answer (score 0):

The [Web 2.0](http://web20show.com/) Show is a podcast about emerging technologies commonly referred to as "Web 2.0", and is hosted by Josh Owens and Adam Stacoviak.

Answer (score 0):

Check out our new podcast at [Crafty Coders](http://craftycoders.com/?tag=/podcast).  It covers programming topics (mostly .net, but also other languages and topics).

Answer (score 0):

[The SitePoint Podcast](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/category/podcast/) hosts are Patrick O’Keefe (@ifroggy), Stephan Segraves (@ssegraves), Brad Williams (@williamsba), and Kevin Yank (@sentience). (@%twitter username%)

Answer (score 0):

[Buzz Out Load - CNET](http://bol.cnet.com)

Answer (score 0):

I never miss the following :-

a) Hanselminutes

b) RunAsradio

c) The Thirsty Developers

d) DotnetRocks

e) DeepFriedBytes

f) [Pixel8](http://community.infragistics.com/pixel8/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've been listening to Tanked Podcast. It's three friends that hang out and talk about tech, movies, video games, and they talk about the odd stuff that happens every week on the web.  These guys are a blast and have way to much fun!

Answer (score 0):

[Thinkcode.tv](http://thinkcode.tv)

Answer (score 0):

[5by5 Studios](http://5by5.tv/), hosted by Dan Benjamin, has some interesting podcasts. Some are specific to a technology (like ExpressionEngine and Ruby), some are focused on people (interviews), and others are discussion on the industry news.

- [The Ruby Show](http://5by5.tv/rubyshow) née Rails Envy.
- [The Pipeline](http://5by5.tv/pipeline), interview shows.
- [The Dev Show](http://5by5.tv/devshow), focused on web development, not just Ruby.
- [The Conversation](http://5by5.tv/conversation), discussion on current topics.
- [The Big Web Show](http://5by5.tv/bigwebshow), more front-end oriented shows (like HTML5 and CSS3.)

Some (or all?) are recorded live. You can find them on iTunes as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Hack Radio](http://www.hackradiolive.org)

Answer (score 0):

The [OS News podcast](http://www.osnews.com/files/podcast.xml) is, unsurprisingly, the podcast for [OS News](http://www.osnews.com/).  OS News is a site mostly dedicated to operating systems, but also covers a range of general technology, hardware and computing topics.