# Lectures available as MP3/podcasts?

Tags: computer-science, podcast

Are there any particularly good university lectures available online for download as MP3 (or some other audio format)? I am particularly interested in hearing some of the more advanced classes that I didn't get to take in my engineering degree, like compilers, operating systems, AI, cryptography, etc.

There is another question on [CS video lectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119238/what-are-your-favorite-cs-video-lectures), but I would like to listen to lectures on my MP3 player.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123120/which-universities-have-comp-sc-lectures-online

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[UC Berkeley](http://webcast.berkeley.edu/courses.php) offers audio versions of lectures. If you pick a class from the unfiltered list of all classes you can subscribe to a feed which pushes .aac files.

Answer (score 6):

Introduction to Algorithms at MIT's OpenCourseWare:

http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-046JFall-2005/LectureNotes/index.htm

And really, MIT's OCW in general.

edit: Also, if you go to the iTunes Store on click "iTunes U" on the left, you'll see iTunes U, which is a collection of *free* audio and video lectures that academic institutions post. There aren't *too* many in-depth CS lectures, but if you do a Power Search for "computer science" or something like that, you'll find some CS and CE topics.

Answer (score 5):

[Stanford Engineering Everywhere](http://see.stanford.edu/SEE/Courses.aspx) (also on iTunes)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind a slightly more academic source, software-engineering radio ( http://www.se-radio.net/) is great.

Answer (score 1):

About the time [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html#) first came out, [this series of lectures](http://courses.ece.uiuc.edu/ece498/al1/) was made available on NVIDIA's web site.

Answer (score 0):

[What good technology podcasts are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there) is a similar, very popular question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some (mentioned here included), and with all due regret I must say that there are probably none worth listening. The lectures themselves are quite good, but the material is just not suited to the listening only - the lecturers keep referring to their whiteboard drawings, slides etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the Berkeley course "[Physics C10](http://muller.lbl.gov/teaching/Physics10/PffP.html)". The more informal name for it is Physics for future Presidents (PffP). It is both very informative and entertaining.

RSS feed for the latest installment, audio version: [autumn 2009](http://webcast.berkeley.edu/media/common/rss/Letters_and_Science_C70V__001__Physics_C10__001_Fall_2009_Audio__webcast.rss). It is in MP4 format; in earlier years it was in MP3 format.