# What are the good SQL Podcasts out there?

Tags: sql, sql-server, podcast

inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there) since i do not find any good sql casts out there and i fail to find any good ones to this day online.

Comment: Too bad there are no more reactions to this questions. I decided to accept the one which podcasts i do like the most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't listen to it (or any SQL podcasts for that matter), but I know of Greg Low's [SQL Down Under](http://www.sqldownunder.com/) and I believe it has a pretty good reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Excellent question, I am always on the look out for good contet.

There are some good podcasts by the likes of Brent Ozar and chums over at SQL Server Pedia.

http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/SQL_Server_Tutorials

Cheers, John