# Good C# focused blogs and/or podcasts?

Tags: c#, blogs, podcast

Are there any good C# focused blogs and/or podcasts out there?

Comment: Are you interested just the language C#?

Comment: While Googling for "C# podcast" does return hits, it doesn't exactly relate how good or useful they are. In this case, I figure asking the community will give better results.

Comment: Make this a Community Wiki

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551315/which-c-net-blogs-do-you-read

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/) works on the C# team and often talks about language design choices. As for podcasts, I would check out [.NET Rocks!](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx) not exactly c# or even always .NET specific, but still might help you out some.

Answer (score 33):

Audio Podcasts:

- [.NET Rocks](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/)
- [CodeCast](http://feeds.feedburner.com/codemag/codecast)
- [Coding QA](http://www.codingqa.com/rss)
- [Deep Fried Bytes](http://feeds.feedburner.com/deepfriedbytes)
- [Hanselminutes](http://feeds.feedburner.com/Hanselminutes)
- [Herding Code](http://herdingcode.com/?feed=rss2)
- [Jesse Liberty YapCast](http://feeds.feedburner.com/jesselibertyyapcast)
- [Pluralcast](http://feeds.feedburner.com/pluralcast)
- [TheSmackdown](http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheSmackdown)
- [Spaghetti Code Podcasts](http://feeds.feedburner.com/SpaghettiCodePodcasts)
- [Ms Dev Show](http://msdevshow.com)

Answer (score 6):

Checkout Scott Hansleman's podcast, [Hanselminutes](http://www.hanselminutes.com/). Scott talks about various .NET related tools and technologies every week and is always very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there) - tons of useful links

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

- [Visual C# Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/default.aspx)
- [C-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com)
- [Csharpfriends](http://www.csharpfriends.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the language C#, I would recommend

1. [C# team blogs](http://www.csharp411.com/blogs-from-microsoft-c-development-team/) and
2. [C# Frequently Asked Questions](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/) where the team posts

Make sure you read [Krzysztof Cwalina blog of .NET framework guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/).

Answer (score 0):

Visual C# Community on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336717.aspx).

They have MVPs blogs, twittes and some good links :)

Answer (score 0):

[HerdingCode](http://herdingcode.com/) is a podcast I quite enjoy, it's run by 4 .NET bloggers. Although it's not exactly C# specific, it's in the area.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything purely in C#, but if you're interested in seeing code, try these...

1. A code-focussed video podcast, often in C#: http://www.dnrtv.com/.
2. Also, http://www.dimecasts.net/.

DNRTV definitely had some nice Bill Wagner episodes you'd be interested in.