# Keeping abreast with technology

Tags: linq, silverlight, model-view-controller

I know this is not a technical question, but this is something I believe could be best answered by the technology community. I've been in software development for ~2 years now, but most of the time, it has been a learn as is needed experience. I was recently asked by a friend on how to go about getting a strong foothold on technology so as to be able to easily adapt to new technology that comes up every day.

I'm not sure how to answer his question as my way of approaching this situation has been learn as you need. How would you suggest someone proceed if they were getting into Microsoft technologies today? Where would they start, and how would they proceed? To be able to expand their knowledge to the new advances we see everyday (linq, silverlight, entity framework, mvc framework and the ever expanding list).

Basically I think my question is a mix of both "how to be a better programmer" and how to get to the "next level" in technology (where you are no longer an intermediate programmer, but able to see the whole picture and easily assimilate new technology)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to try superuser.com.  If you go to http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/ then you can get a beta key for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this post by the Misfit Geek could help you out a bit.  I think it gives some great tips and gives some good advice on how a respected technologist has stayed up on technology.

[How did you learn what you know](http://misfitgeek.com/blog/i-rsquo-m-asked-how-did-you-learn-what-you-know/)

Hope these help.  I also agree that podcast are a great source of info, at least to point you to the best new technologies.  I listen to .Net Rocks, Hanselminutes, HerdingCode, and DeepFriedBytes just to name a few.  I also follow some good .net releated blogs such as CodeBetter, Devlicio.us, and Los Techies.

Good luck!

Comment: new link: http://www.misfitgeek.com/i%E2%80%99m-asked-how-did-you-learn-what-you-know/

Answer (score 8):

One thing I enjoy is to listen to technology podcasts while I commute, exercise or do household work. You will net become an expert alone by listening to podcasts, but you will get a lot of input. In particular I enjoy [.NET Rocks!](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/) but Stack Overflow also has a [podcast](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html) to name a few.

Comment: Yep, one of the few advantages of a long commute!

Answer (score 5):

[Read, do and try new things.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76364/what-is-the-single-most-effective-thing-you-did-to-improve-your-programming-skill) Do that for a few years you'll eventually end up an experienced programmer.

Answer (score 4):

I spend at least 1 hour a day just reading blogs, and listening to podcasts.  You cant possibly get involved in everything new that comes along, but having knowledge of what's new is just as important as trying new things out.

If you want to specialise in one thing, then that's fine, but always try to include new technologies into your projects, and look for better solutions to things you have done in the past.

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow what the technical community is interested in. Blogs are the best way that I've found to do this. Pick at least 50 that cover a wide range of topics, and you'll know what is coming down the pipe.

Comment: Being aware of new technologies and understanding them aren't exactly the same thing.  Reading blogs seems like it would be just a small fraction of getting "the whole picture."

Answer (score 3):

Keep involved in podcasts and blogs. Set aside at least 15 minutes a day to ready them or listen to them. Take their ideas, find which ones apply to you or are interested and add it to your personal development plan to learn them.

Here are a few previous posts regarding these:

[Podcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there)

OR

[c# blogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950342/good-c-focused-blogs-and-or-podcasts)

Answer (score 2):

- Interesting project + new technology = motivated learning.

There is no alternative to getting your hands dirty. Take one of the ideas you've had rolling around in your head and implement it using buzzword technologies. Be prepared to realize many hyped technologies are mostly just hype. Hopefully you will find some real gems, change your perceptions of what is possible, and add some tools to your toolbox all while achieving a goal.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the list of [Top 200 blogs for software developers](http://www.noop.nl/2009/06/top-200-blogs-for-developers-q2-2009.html).  Try to read some of them and subscribe to what you like or find useful.

Blogs are great for spotting trends and finding some advice about the newest technologies, but if you want to learn something in-depth, you need books.  Try to read 3 or 4 every year.

Finally, local user groups.  Find and meet your fellow developers face-to-face and find out what they're doing and what's on their minds.

Answer (score 1):

Attend meetings of local user groups.