# As a .NET beginner, what should I learn and where can I find open source projects?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm beginner programmer in the amazing world named ".Net".

I've a lot of questions

- well, what I should learn C# or Vb.net
- What's the best blogs which talk about .Net technology and Open source projects
- Where can I find good tutorials, free books and ideas of projects
- how can I progress in ".Net"
- please, share your knowledge , your OPML of your favorite blogs or web sites about ".Net "

I'm waiting your advices, opinions, etc.

Comment: SO Question: [Open Source C# Projects That Have High Code Quality?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143088/open-source-c-projects-that-have-high-code-quality)

Comment: This is a duplicate of a lot of questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as which language you should learn, well what are your experiences thus far? I prefer C# over VB.NET. Though, eventually, you should be able to program in VB.NET even if you say with C# as your primary language (the same is true vice versa for VB.NET). You might want to check the syntax of each language and see which you prefer just by first glance. You will probably find that whenever code examples are provided for .NET and both languages aren't present, typically the examples are in C#. This is not a big deal though. I find C# (and similar languages) to be less verbose but that is a preference. Here are some good resources. I highly recommend the LearnVisualStudio.NET videos; start with the beginner tutorials and advance to more advanced topics.

Some great resources include:

http://www.dotnetrocks.com (podcast)
http://www.se-radio.net (general software engineering podcast)
http://www.haacked.com (Phil Haack's blog)
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/ (Scott Guthrie's blog)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551315/which-c-net-blogs-do-you-read (previous question with a good list of blogs)

http://www.learnvisualstudio.net (good place to find video courses, cheap)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423/best-net-podcasts (previous question)
[What good technology podcasts are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there) (more podcasts)

Open Source projects:

http://www.codeplex.com is great for Open Source .NET projects.

Also:

http://csharp-source.net/ (not bad, some projects are old and not maintained)

http://sourceforge.net/softwaremap/trove_list.php?form_cat=271 C# as SourceForge

[Open Source C# Opportunities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765/open-source-c-opportunities) (previous question with good infor)

Answer (score 2):

Also check http://www.codeproject.com/

Comment: darn... only a minute faster than me...

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with [Fabulous Adventures In Coding](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/default.aspx), which is a great blog by one of the people who actually work on C#. Then i'd also take a look at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx). Finally, you can't forget [Joel Spolsky's web site](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/)!

For Regexes, look no further than [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). [Cosmos](http://www.gocosmos.org/index.en.aspx) is a neat project though a little heavy for beginners, and [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) has the best VS addin this side of the earth! Personally, i don't like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) but plenty of other people do.

(marking it CW so anyone can contribute)

Answer (score 2):

Excellent suggestions so far. Another site to always keep in mind for open source code is [Google Code.](http://code.google.com) Plus Google has excellent search features for finding just about anything in their code base.

Answer (score 1):

Things i am following

https://stackoverflow.com/

http://www.codeplex.com/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/default.aspx

Comment: I don't think C# in depth is a book intended for beginner programmers.

Comment: ya u r right.In first itself job skeet is written its for experience candidates. Hmmmmm ...

Comment: Yes, please don't recommend C# in Depth for beginners - it'll put them off my writing for life!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a Comparison of C# vs VB.NET [here](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html)

Also this [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/vbnet_c__difference.aspx) in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com) describes the complete differences between C# and VB.NET. You will get large number of opensource projects from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com)

You can find an exiting project [TextPad](http://www.dotnetspider.com/projects/397-TextPad--A-New-Text-Editor.aspx), which will help you to learn more in C#

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in web development, check http://www.asp.net.

Also, checkout [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/magazine/default.aspx), [4 Guys From Rolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/), and the [Linq Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I also had these question in my mind when I started learning .NET. I prefer C# over VB. But then its purely a personal choice. In my view start with a nice book like Beginning Microsoft Visual C# 2008 or Head First C#. And the online source which I find very useful [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As to your question whether to learn VB.NET or C#...  Well, there are personal preferences and there are realities.

If you want to make a living out of this, keep in mind that relatively and generally speaking c# will make you more employable.

Example.  As of right now, Dice lists 4421 matches for c# versus 1131 for vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend "Beginning ASP.NET 3.5 in C# 2008: From Novice to Professional" from Mathew MacDonald. It does not rely on deep C# knowledge and even for someone who knows C# it's interesting to read. I'm almost half through, and it is really nice to read.

Don't be shocked by the almost 1000 pages - lots of code listings and pictures are inside.

I think there is even a VB.NET edition, but I prefer C# - and I still think that this is the language Microsoft puts more focus on.

Answer (score 0):

For GDI (graphics) programming in C# / VB.Net, look at the "Beginners guide to GDI+" section at [bobpowell.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145656/http://bobpowell.net/faqmain.aspx).

I have worked through many of the advanced topics, and they're very well written and give great examples.