# What is the best place to get podcasts for improving C# programming skills?

Tags: c#

I am always looking for places to learn more.

Which places do you recommend for podcasts about programming?

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well these are not strictly podcasts, but I recommend Scott Guthrie's (Vice President of Microsoft's Developer Division) blog and twitter feeds. He posts tutorials and links to other tutorials and videos. And he should know the good tutorials!

[Scott Gu Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/)

[Scott Gu Twitter](http://twitter.com/scottgu)

Answer (score 3):

http://dimecasts.net/ - 10 minute bites of information, great for a lunchbreak or a quick intro

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for more than one podcast so I hope this helps answers your question, but... [.NET Rocks!](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/) is an excellent podcast for C# and .NET in general.