# Programming podcast recommendations

Tags: podcast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What good technology podcasts are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there)

Travelling an hour each way to work in the car I have taken to juicing my ears and brain by listening to podcasts. Currently this includes .NET Rocks, The Java Posse and (for the few I could find) Hacker Medley. Could anyone recommend any others?

My background is .NET, Java and I write some Android apps in my spare time. Any recommendations along these lines would very cool.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76467/what-programming-screencasts-podcast-resources-do-you-know

Comment: Thanks nos, this list is good!

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out [Hanselminutes from Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselminutes.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Even though they're no longer recording new episodes, a pretty goon one was [Stackoverflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/)'s own podcast.

I also like [FLOSS Weekly](http://www.twit.tv/floss).

You can check out [IT Conversations Networks](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/). They have a variety of PODCASTs listed.